# Splitting main file into modules in C

Tags: c

I have three files as such:

module.c:

```
void bar() {
  foo();
}
```

module.h: (i didn't put the include guard for simplicity)

```
void bar();
```

main.c

```
void foo() {
  //some code
}
int main() {
  bar();
}
```

when compiling main.c and module.c, module.c returns an error saying foo() is not defined. How can i fix this up?
Basically, i wanted to take my actual main file, which was pretty large, and split up parts of it to other files for readability, but those functions call other functions found in main

Comment: This goes against the design of modules.  The module should not know about `foo` if `main.c` depends on that module.  Either split `foo` out into another module or make it part of `module.c`.

Comment: Create a `main.h` and add a declaration for `foo` in it, just like you did with `bar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tricky because of the directions your dependencies are going.

I can split your code into three compilation units: main.c, module.c, and foo.c

If you do this, you don't have any foo code in main, main only calls bar, and bar includes foo, which is defined in foo.

main.c

```
#include "module.h"

int main() {
    bar();
}
```

module.c

```
#include "foo.h"

void bar() {
    foo();
}
```

foo.c

```
void foo() {

}
```

Best of all is that you don't need to declare foo outside of foo.h, or bar outside of module.h.

Comment: The only thing I would add to this is to consider whether `foo` is even needed outside of `module.c`.  If it's an internal function that only has meaning within `module.c` then there's no reason to provide it in any headers.  Instead it can be implemented in that file as a static.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `module.h` could also define `void foo();` thus `module.c` would implement `foo` too. On the other hand, if `bar` depends indirectly on `foo`, then maybe `module.c` should include `another_module.h` implemented by `another_module.c`.

Answer (score -1):

Put prototype definitions for *all* your functions into module.h:

```
int main(int argc,char **argv);
void foo(void);
void bar(void);
int fludger(int abc,char *str);
```

You get the side benefit that in addition to putting any function in any .c file you wish, you no longer need to order the functions within a given .c file, based upon what calls what [e.g. before if foo called bar, bar would have to be defined *above* foo]

Comment: Why on earth would you prototype `main`?

Comment: @paddy force of habit.  it does no harm and since I use a perl script to auto-generate these prototypes for my own stuff, it doesn't special case for main.

Comment: Actually, I am voting this down.  Prototyping `foo` in `module.h` and implementing in `main.c` is not good practice.  The header should describe functions that are provided by its source file.  It should _not_ describe functions that are provided by _other_ source files.  This answer seems to be a sledge-hammer to "make it work", rather than explaining why the original code has a broken design.

Comment: @paddy OP wants a simple split.  I routinely do the split based on directory, not module.  That is, library.h.  But, it depends on the use case as to which is more appropriate.  Your statement about one header for one module, based on .c file is not true.  See the linux kernel source for copious counter examples where protos from multiple .c files end up in a single .h

Comment: That's because the Linux kernel is written by people who understand special reasons why you would do that.  As a general rule, you don't do that.

Comment: @paddy Yes, and I'm one of them.  A "module" can be split among several .c files.  Herein, OP has only has only one "module" [that can be discerned--since he didn't detail what the splits are/were and whether he intended to move them to a new directory to create a library].  He's got a program and he just wants to split up a large .c file--that's all.  You can have one struct/class definition per .h or several [related] in one .h.  This arrangement is a design _choice_ and not a _rule_ [general or otherwise]